# Properly Unit testing a QItemDelegate

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt5

I'm currently implementing unit tests for a class I have that contains a QAbstractTableModel, QSortFilerProxyModel, QTableView, and a QStyledItemDelegate.  Testing the model is easy enough.  The delegate, which decides how each cell is painted (and ultimately what the user sees) is another issue.

The crux of the issue is that paint() is called w/ a QModelIndex as a parameter, which has a pointer to the model.  It generally grabs the data from there, and decides what color to paint, how many decimals to use in the case of a double, etc.  With QModelIndexes being "internal" by nature, what's the best way of going about simulating the delegate painting an index?  I could have my model create an index, and just pass that to the delegate for unit tests.  That seems a bit tacky to me though.

Thoughts?

Comment: You could abstract the deciding logic into another class and test that. If you find yourself in a situation where you want/need to test internals of a class it indicates design smell (bad design). However note that (unit) testing is invasive programming technique so it is not uncommon that your design while perfectly fine conflicts with testing demands.

Comment: Cheers.  I know there's a balance of exposing things to tests, and tight design...  As for testing the internals, it's more or less to programatically make sure I (or another programmer) doesn't break something inadvertently.

Comment: I came to believe that this idea is actually idealistic. You are designing an app that does something. Proving that some internal part is working is meaningless therefore only meaningful testing is of the exposed (public/external) behaviour (that something). In the end that is the only thing that matters. Just my 2 cents.